# Compute the optimized palette for RGB image

Tags: image, apl

```
 r←n optimal img;bmp;bin;rgb
 ;i;p;v;b;euclid;most
 ;m;⎕IO
 ⍝ compute optimal palette
 ⍝ it is recomended using
 ⍝ a shrinked image
 ⎕IO←0
 r←⍬
 ⍝ 12996=114*2=(⌊0.45×255)*2, 0.45 is the threshold constant from the paper.
 euclid←{∧/12996≤+⌿×⍨r(-⍤1 0⍤¯1)⍥((3⍴256)∘⊤)⍵}
 most←(((⊢⍳⌈/)⊢/)⌷⊣/){⍺(+/⍵)}⌸
 ⍝ 16*3 binning map, instead of 10*3 bins used in the paper.
 bmp←16⊥⌊img÷16
 p←,rgb←256⊥img
 ⍝ vote
 i←0
 :Repeat
     v←euclid rgb
 ⍝ count bins
     b←bmp most⍥,v
     r,←p[⊃⍒,(⊢×{+/,⍵}⌺21 21)bmp=b]
     i+←1
 :Until i=n ⍝ User has to specify the number of colors.
 ⍝ fin, translate the compressed palette
 r←(3 1,≢r)⍴(3⍴256)⊤r
```

The above APL code is an altered implementation of https://v-sense.scss.tcd.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/IMVIP18_palette.pdf

The input is an array of `3 Y X` describes the RGB image of size `X×Y`.
The output is an array of `3 1 X` describes the palette of length `X`.
The max value of these arrays are assumed to be 255.

I'd like to have comments on APL coding style, performance, and space efficiency.